# Refraction at parabolic surfaces

Tags: refraction

Why is it that we don't find discussion of refraction at **parabolic** surfaces while we find plenty of discussions of refraction at spherical, elliptic and hyperbolic surfaces?

Could you please give any references that discuss at introductory level, the topic, Refraction at parabolic surfaces?

Comment: Is refraction on parabolic surfaces useful? If it isn't, then that's probably a major reason. Aspherical lenses are usually designed with far more complicated parameters than the above choices.